# I have numeric type in sql what is the corresponding mapping data type in pojo class

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, pojo

Hai I am using **MS SQL SERVER** and **hibernate**. I had declared **numeric data type** in MS SQL SERVER for a particular column. Can anyone help me with what type should I declare for this type(numeric) in pojo class for mapping.

Comment: What precision of that numeric datatype do you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please go through the below for numeric data types

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms187752.aspx